How to format the scale bar in my heatmap to display words instead of numbers?
I want to make a heatmap using seaborn and want to format the scale bar in such a way that it displays no numbers only low and high.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Force Heatmap
force_df = pd.read_csv()

custom_palette = sns.color_palette("coolwarm", as_cmap=True)

ax = sns.heatmap(force_df.pivot_table(index="z-axis", columns="x-axis", values="Force"), cmap=custom_palette, cbar_kws={'label': 'Force', 'shrink': 0.5, 'aspect':10})

ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.title("Force Heatmap")
plt.show()


